# LINQ and Null Coallescing

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to get the null coallescing operator to work with a LINQ expression in ASP.NET MVC.

Here is my expression.

```
<%= Html.Encode(item.Ring.Keys.Single<ProjectOne.Key>( k => k.Literal.Value == "Class" ).KeyValue) %>
```

Basically, it finds an instance of the "Key" class based on the given Name, the name being the title, the result being the Value of the Key. I want to return a null string if it doesn't find a matching key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
item.Ring.Keys
    .Where(k => k.Literal.Value == "Class")
    .Select(k => k.KeyValue)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

That's assuming you want a null reference if it's not found. If you're rather have an empty string, just add `?? ""` at the end:

```
item.Ring.Keys
    .Where(k => k.Literal.Value == "Class")
    .Select(k => k.KeyValue)
    .SingleOrDefault() ?? "";
```

There's another option which I don't like as much:

```
(item.Ring.Keys
     .SingleOrDefault(k => k.Literal.Value == "Class") 
         ?? new ProjectOne.Key { KeyValue = null }).KeyValue;
```

Comment: Well, it needs to be in the Lamda expression. I can't rightly use the full LINQ syntax in the View. That's what I can't seem to get to work right.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Yes, this works. I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do it, to where that object will always return something appropriate if it isn't found...